# Error in setting max features parameter in Isolation Forest algorithm using sklearn

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, scikit-learn, random-forest

I'm trying to train a dataset with 357 features using [Isolation Forest sklearn implementation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.html#sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest). I can successfully train and get results when the max features variable is set to 1.0 (the default value).

However when max features is set to 2, it gives the following error:

```
ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. 
Model n_features is 2 and input n_features is 357
```

[image]

It also gives the same error when the feature count is 1 (int) and not 1.0 (float).

How I understood was that when the feature count is 2 (int), two features should be considered in creating each tree. Is this wrong? How can I change the max features parameter?

The code is as follows:

```
from sklearn.ensemble.iforest import IsolationForest

def isolation_forest_imp(dataset):

    estimators = 10
    samples = 100
    features = 2
    contamination = 0.1
    bootstrap = False
    random_state = None
    verbosity = 0

    estimator = IsolationForest(n_estimators=estimators, max_samples=samples, contamination=contamination,
                                     max_features=features,
                                     bootstrap=boostrap, random_state=random_state, verbose=verbosity)

    model = estimator.fit(dataset)
```

Comment: Thats an issue in scikit version 0.18 or below. See the [issue here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/5732). Update your scikit-version to 0.20

Comment: Thanks @VivekKumar , that seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation it states:

```
max_features : int or float, optional (default=1.0)
    The number of features to draw from X to train each base estimator.

        - If int, then draw `max_features` features.
        - If float, then draw `max_features * X.shape[1]` features.
```

So, 2 should mean take two features and 1.0 should mean take all of the features, 0.5 take half and so on, from what I understand.

I think this could be a bug, since, taking a look in IsolationForest's fit:

```
# Isolation Forest inherits from BaseBagging 
# and when _fit is called, BaseBagging takes care of the features correctly
super(IsolationForest, self)._fit(X, y, max_samples,
                                          max_depth=max_depth,
                                          sample_weight=sample_weight)
 # however, when after _fit the decision_function is called using X - the whole sample - not taking into account the max_features
 self.threshold_ = -sp.stats.scoreatpercentile(
            -self.decision_function(X), 100. * (1. - self.contamination))
```

then:

```
    # when the decision function _validate_X_predict is called, with X unmodified, 
    # it calls the base estimator's (dt) _validate_X_predict with the whole X
    X = self.estimators_[0]._validate_X_predict(X, check_input=True)

   ... 

   # from tree.py:
   def _validate_X_predict(self, X, check_input):
        """Validate X whenever one tries to predict, apply, predict_proba"""
        if self.tree_ is None:
            raise NotFittedError("Estimator not fitted, "
                                 "call `fit` before exploiting the model.")

        if check_input:
            X = check_array(X, dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csr")
            if issparse(X) and (X.indices.dtype != np.intc or
                                X.indptr.dtype != np.intc):
                raise ValueError("No support for np.int64 index based "
                                 "sparse matrices")
        # so, this check fails because X is the original X, not with the max_features applied
        n_features = X.shape[1]
        if self.n_features_ != n_features:
            raise ValueError("Number of features of the model must "
                             "match the input. Model n_features is %s and "
                             "input n_features is %s "
                             % (self.n_features_, n_features))

        return X
```

So, I am not sure on how you can handle this. Maybe figure out the percentage that leads to just the two features you need - even though I am not sure it'll work as expected.

Note: I am using scikit-learn v.0.18

**Edit**: as @Vivek Kumar commented this is an issue and upgrading to 0.20 should do the trick.